# Getting users information from moodle

Tags: moodle

How to get the section's user information (like name, password)? Is there any method that returns it?

I'm trying the function "core_user_get_users_by_field", but it isn't works. That's I've done:

String serverurl = url + "/webservice/rest/server.php" + "?wstoken=" + token + "&wsfunction=" + functionName;

obs: The server was constructed using REST.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works for me

/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=xxx&wsfunction=core_user_get_users_by_field&field=id&values[0]=2

2 is the user id.

You can use any field that uniquely identifies the user. eg: field=username

You can also retrieve more than one user at a time eg: values[0]=2&values[1]=3

This is assuming the function was added as a web service following these instructions

http://docs.moodle.org/25/en/Using_web_services

Comment: I'm using this function, but its not working. If I create a token directly on moodle, it works, but it doesnt if I try using the function

Comment: For example, if I try manually
http://desenvolvimento.imd.ufrn.br/qmmoodle/login/token.php?username=carloscaval&password=Abc%3E1234&service=moodle_mobile_app
It works.
But I need do it by webservices. like this:
http://desenvolvimento.imd.ufrn.br/qmmoodle/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=b2b206934e8142dede2afa3bd31ced75&wsfunction=core_user_get_users_by_field&moodlewsrestformat=json&field=username&values%5B0%5D=carloscaval

Comment: The second url looks correct so its something in the set up that isn't correct - what version of Moodle are you using?

Comment: The newest one. 
v.2.6

Answer (score 1):

There is global object called `$USER` in moodle, this object contains  all information about user,  So where you want these information just access like,

```
 global $USER; // <= don't forget to write this before to access
 $USER->username;
 $USER->firstname;
 $USER->lastname;
 $USER->password;
```

Comment: This will only work from within the Moodle codebase, plugins etc. - not from a webservice call via REST.

Answer (score 0):

Its works with:

```
https://url.moodle.xyz/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=XXXXXXX&wsfunction=core_user_get_users_by_field&field=id&values%5B0%5D=1306
```

The query parameters:

- wsfunction=core_user_get_users_by_field
- **field**=id
- **values[0]**=1234

*values[0]* is user id.

Answer (score 0):

**To  get moodle userdetails based on user name you can use like this :**

/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=8888&wsfunction=core_user_get_users_by_field&field=username&values[0]=mark

**To get JSON data Use :**

/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=8888&wsfunction=core_user_get_users_by_field&field=username&values[0]=mark&moodlewsrestformat=json

Answer (score 0):

Via curl POST request:

```
curl \
-X POST \
--data-urlencode "wstoken=123456789..." \
--data-urlencode "wsfunction=core_user_get_users_by_field" \
--data-urlencode "field=id" \
--data-urlencode "values[0]=123456" \
https://moodle.domain.tld/webservice/rest/server.php
```

As Russell England said:

> [...] use any field that uniquely identifies the user. eg: `field=username`